# Custom Shortcodes Giving error on development site

Tags: shortcode, errors

I have an existing site that uses custom shortcodes. when i tried to transfer them to a new theme & dev site, it gives me an error. The shortcode is about tabbed content. You can see the error here: https://dev.brothermartin.com/extracurriculars/academic-games/ and this is it:

Notice: Undefined variable: tab3_button in /home/brothermartin18/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/Brother_Martin_2018/lib/admin/shortcodes/shortcodes.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined variable: tab4_button in /home/brothermartin18/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/Brother_Martin_2018/lib/admin/shortcodes/shortcodes.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined variable: tab5_button in /home/brothermartin18/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/Brother_Martin_2018/lib/admin/shortcodes/shortcodes.php on line 60

This is the code related to the shortcode:

```
function mbiz_tabbed_box( $atts, $content = null ) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'tab1' => '',
  'tab2' => '',
  'tab3' => '',
  'tab4' => '',
  'tab5' => '',
  ), $atts ) );

if ($tab1) $tab1_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab1">' . esc_attr($tab1) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab2) $tab2_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab2">' . esc_attr($tab2) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab3) $tab3_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab3">' . esc_attr($tab3) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab4) $tab4_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab4">' . esc_attr($tab4) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab5) $tab5_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab5">' . esc_attr($tab5) . '</a></li>';

return '<div class="tabs-style1"><div class="tabs-navigation"><ul class="tabs-nav">'
        . $tab1_button . $tab2_button . $tab3_button . $tab4_button . $tab5_button .
        '</ul></div><div class="tabs-content">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('tabbed_box', 'mbiz_tabbed_box');
```

Does anyone have any simple fixes for this? It only occurs when 5 tabs are not utilized. I didn't create these, so having a hard time troubleshooting.

Comment: You’re only defining $tab5_button, for example, if $tab5 has a value, but you use $tab5_button in the return statement no mater what. The button variables need to have a fallback value so that they exist when the return statement runs.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Do you have any code adjustments/samples you can provide? I don't normally write shortcodes, just develop themes.

Comment: You never give those variables default values, so if the tab is false, then the variable never gets created. Yet you always use the variable. When it isn't created, and you use it anyway, PHP creates a default value and creates a warning, and the warning is what you're seeing. Also avoid using `extract` like the plague, it's very bad practice and causes lots of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variables first. See code below:

```
function mbiz_tabbed_box( $atts, $content = null ) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'tab1' => '',
  'tab2' => '',
  'tab3' => '',
  'tab4' => '',
  'tab5' => '',
  ), $atts ) );

$tab1_button = $tab2_button = $tab3_button = $tab4_button = $tab5_button = '';

if ($tab1) $tab1_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab1">' . esc_attr($tab1) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab2) $tab2_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab2">' . esc_attr($tab2) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab3) $tab3_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab3">' . esc_attr($tab3) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab4) $tab4_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab4">' . esc_attr($tab4) . '</a></li>';
if ($tab5) $tab5_button = '<li><a href="#" title="tab5">' . esc_attr($tab5) . '</a></li>';

return '<div class="tabs-style1"><div class="tabs-navigation"><ul class="tabs-nav">'
        . $tab1_button . $tab2_button . $tab3_button . $tab4_button . $tab5_button .
        '</ul></div><div class="tabs-content">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('tabbed_box', 'mbiz_tabbed_box');
```

Another solution would be to build a string then return it, without using separate variables.

```
$out = '<div class="tabs-style1"><div class="tabs-navigation"><ul class="tabs-nav">';
    if ($tab1) $out .= '<li>whatever</li>';
    if ($tab2) $out .= '<li>whatever</li>';
    if ($tab3) $out .= '<li>whatever</li>';
    if ($tab4) $out .= '<li>whatever</li>';
    if ($tab5) $out .= '<li>whatever</li>';
$out .= '</ul></div><div class="tabs-content">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div>';

return $out;
```

Comment: The first option worked. Thanks for your help. Was a lifesaver!

Comment: You are welcome! Although I would recommend the second one, as it's more compact and more readable.

Comment: It won't be used going forward, so it's just any old blog posts that utilize it won't have errors. Most everything is being redone.